# Ember-data: nested model properties access errors out

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I'm facing a strange issue accessing nested model properties in my handlebars template.
My JSON feed looks like this:

```
{
"hic": {
    "id": "1",
    "tree": {
        "id": "1",
        "folder": [
            {name: "test1"},
            {name: "test2"}
        ]
    ...
    }
}
}
```

When I try to display my folder objects via the following handlebars template:

```
<ul>
    {{#with tree}}
        {{#each folder}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
</ul>
```

it errors out with: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined.**

This *workaround* brings the desired result.

```
<ul>
    {{#with tree.data.hasMany}}
        {{#each folder}}
            <li>{{name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
</ul>
```

Is this an issue with ember-data or am I doing something wrong?

Note:
I wasn't able to reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle. When I create the *Hic-model* via *createRecord()* everything works as expected.

The json-feed can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42353723/hic.json).
Thats my [app.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42353723/app.js). I can also provide a full node.js-project.

Comment: I'm a real ember newbie, but is there some kind of convention saying that "folder" should be plural in your json? Maybe that's why folders are not accessible? Just a guess...

Comment: I configured in *app.js* that the plural of folder is folder: `DS.Adapter.configure('plurals', {
 hic: 'hic',
 tree: 'tree',
 folder: 'folder'
});`.

Comment: could you add the id for tree in the json feed please ?

Comment: The [json feed](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42353723/hic.json) does include ids for all element/models. I just forgot to mention it in the sample above.

Answer (score 3):

Root cause seems to be the embedded *belongsTo*-relationship.
This pull request fixes this issue: [Extract embedded `belongsTo` records properly](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/637).
Many thanks to [sandstrom](https://github.com/sandstrom)!